# Cut off the exponential random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter (mean) $\mu = 2$, its density is given by 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}, \quad \text{for } x > 0$$
For $K > 0$, define a function $\mathrm{sat}_{K}$ that cuts off the values at level $K$ by 
$$\mathrm{sat}_{K}(x) = \begin{cases} x, & \text{if}\ x \leq K, \\ K, & \text{if}\ x > K, \end{cases}$$
and let $Y_K = \mathrm{sat}_{k}(X)$. Explicitly compute the distribution function $F_Y$ of $Y_K$ and sketch it. What type of random variable is $Y_K$ ?

Comment: Posts that merely state a problem are often poorly received.  Please add some context to your Question, such as what you tried, what learning material you suspect the exercise is intended to reinforce, or even what interests you in this problem.  Such details will help Readers to phrase a cogent reply with less guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

If $y\ge K$ you have
$$
F_{Y_K}(y)=P\{Y_K\le y\}=P\{X\in\mathbb{R}\}=1
$$
since $Y_K\le K\le y$ for any value of $X$. Now, if $y\le K$, 
$$
F_{Y_K}(y)=P\{Y_K\le y\}=P\{X\le y\}=F_X(y)=1-e^{-y/2}
$$
so basically you are creating a jump in your distribution function at $y=K$.

Comment: why when $K >= 1/2$, I don't cut anything, thanks!

Comment: Actually I realized that my answer is wrong! You are not cutting the density (that would not be sound probabilistically) but the variable itself. I will rewrite my answer.

Comment: Thank you, GReyes!

Comment: I posted the right answer now.

Comment: Thank you GReyes, I have understood the former two situations. What dose the "create a jump in the distribution function at y = K" really mean? I am still a little confused here.

Comment: Does it means the function is not continuous at y = K?

Comment: Right, that is exactly what happens.